# How can I match the data of two datasets based on dates?

Tags: excel, data-cleaning

I have two different data sets, one with data of the federal funds rate, and another with data of the 10-yr bond yield. However, these data sets are of unequal length. I want to be able to take the input of these two data sets and return only the data points that have a common date between them. How can I do that?

What my data Looks like:

[image: Image 1]

Comment: are you looking for a VBA solution or just plain formulas?

Comment: Look into the `VLookup` function - Made for exactly this purpose....

Comment: Can you manually make a result sheet of what you want to achieve exactly and post it? That way we can see better what you need and help.

Comment: It looks like 10 year has 7/21/2000 duplicated.  Is that a mistake? or what result would you like to see?